# Is it possible to show ons-bottom-toolbar above tabbar?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Is it possible to show ons-bottom-toolbar above tabbar?

I have tried something like:

```
<ons-bottom-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <div style="text-align: center; line-height: 44px">
        <ons-toolbar-button modifier="quiet">
            <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button modifier="quiet">
            <i class="fa fa-backward" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
</ons-bottom-toolbar>

<ons-tabbar var="mainTab">
    <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="home" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="setting.html" label="Settings" icon="gear"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

But it did't work out. Wonder if it is possible to do so using these two Onsen components.